# How to start a swanctl.conf configured tunnel automatically

Tags: debian, systemd, strongswan

Environment: Debian 10, KDE, Full desktop

```
# ipsec --version
Linux strongSwan U5.7.2/K4.19.0-6-amd64

# swanctl --version
strongSwan swanctl 5.7.2

# systemctl status strongswan
● strongswan.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-12-13 09:35:03 -03; 4h 34min ago
  Process: 6067 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ipsec start --nofork (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6067 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

# systemctl status strongswan-swanctl
● strongswan-swanctl.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using swanctl
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan-swanctl.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-12-13 09:11:34 -03; 4h 56min ago
 Main PID: 6373 (charon-systemd)
   Status: "charon-systemd running, strongSwan 5.7.2, Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64, x86_64"
    Tasks: 17 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 8.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/strongswan-swanctl.service
           └─6373 /usr/sbin/charon-systemd
```

After spending almost two days learning and poking around IPSec and IKEv2 I managed to connect to the company gateway (Lancom LCOS, IKEv2 PSK, User-FQDN identities) using strongswan and swanctl.

After a reboot I have to run the following commands:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/swanctl --load-all
```

```
no files found matching '/etc/swanctl/conf.d/*.conf'
loaded ike secret 'ike'
no authorities found, 0 unloaded
no pools found, 0 unloaded
loaded connection 'IKEv2PSK'
successfully loaded 1 connections, 0 unloaded
```

and then `sudo /usr/sbin/swanctl --initiate --child myVpn`

```
[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA myVpn{2}
... lots of log lines ...
initiate completed successfully
```

I'd like to have the tunnel started automatically, maybe using a systemd unit  something like

```
sudo systemctl swanctl-myVpn start
```

However I don't find any documentation how to achieve this, which also makes me wonder if this is a bad idea?

Comment: Do you use the [charon-systemd](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Charon-systemd) daemon? Or the old starter/charon combintation? Which strongSwan version do you use? Also note that the NetworkManager frontend uses a completely separate IKE daemon (charon-nm) that is not configured with swantl.conf/vici.

Comment: ummmm, good question. I guess the newer charon-systemd daemon is running, I posted the status summary above.

Comment: That systemd service unit should automatically load the config when the daemon starts. Check the documentation on how to initiate connections automatically (keyword: _start_action_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ecdsa pointed me into the right direction. Adding a `start_action` to the config is the solution:

```
connections {
    IKEv2PSK {
        remote_addrs = SOME.DYNDNS-IP.COM, 81.81.81.81
        vips = 0.0.0.0
        version = 2
        dpd_delay = 30
        dpd_timeout = 90
        proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
        
        local {
            auth = psk
            id = @@marcwittke@my.company.com
        }
        remote {
            auth = psk
            id = 81.81.81.81
        }
                
        children {
            anicVpn {
                remote_ts = 192.168.0.0/24
                updown = /usr/lib/ipsec/_updown iptables
                esp_proposals = aes256-sha256-modp2048
                start_action = trap   # <----- trap: on traffic | start: on boot
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now a simple ping to a server starts the tunnel. The option `start` could also be used to get the tunnel up and running directly on system start. Source: [swanctl.conf](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Swanctlconf#connectionsltconngtchildrenltchildgt-section)

#### Update

Note that this doesn't work in Ubuntu, because AppArmor prevents the updown-script from running out of the box

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the `start_action = start` option to work on Ubuntu by adding the following to the `/etc/strongswan.d/charon.conf` file:

```
# Section containing a list of scripts (name = path) that are executed when
# the daemon is started.
start-scripts {
   swanctl-creds = swanctl --load-creds --noprompt
   swanctl-conns = swanctl --load-conns
}
```

Comment: In the meantime I am on Fedora and managed to integrate my VPN config into Networkmanager, so I can't confirm this currently. But it looks very promising, thanks for sharing.