# Network Manager plugin for Strongswan won't show pre shred key authentication option

Tags: debian, networkmanager, strongswan

> this was originally the second part of my question here [How to start a swanctl.conf configured tunnel automatically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557032)

Environment: Debian 10, KDE, Full desktop

```
# ipsec --version
Linux strongSwan U5.7.2/K4.19.0-6-amd64

# swanctl --version
strongSwan swanctl 5.7.2

# systemctl status strongswan
● strongswan.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-12-13 09:35:03 -03; 4h 34min ago
  Process: 6067 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ipsec start --nofork (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6067 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

# systemctl status strongswan-swanctl
● strongswan-swanctl.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using swanctl
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan-swanctl.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-12-13 09:11:34 -03; 4h 56min ago
 Main PID: 6373 (charon-systemd)
   Status: "charon-systemd running, strongSwan 5.7.2, Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64, x86_64"
    Tasks: 17 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 8.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/strongswan-swanctl.service
           └─6373 /usr/sbin/charon-systemd
```

My IPSec tunnel (IKEv2, PSK) is up and running. I am able to manage it via swanctl commands on the shell. However, I'd like to use the network manager plugin. But the authentication method `pre shared key` won't show up. What am I missing?

Version info:
`network-manager-strongswan is already the newest version (1.4.4-2).`

[image: networkmanager with strongswan plugin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`network-manager-strongswan` provides the plugin for the GNOME/GTK version of the NetworkManager frontend, which is developed [upstream](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/tree/master/src/frontends/gnome).

The KDE/Plasma version is provided by KDE's NetworkManager (`plasma-nm` package) and is not directly related to the first one (except that they both rely on the `charon-nm` daemon provided by the `strongswan-nm` package). This plugin is developed [downstream](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-nm/tree/master/vpn/strongswan) by different people.

The KDE frontend was started in 2013, before the "original" supported pre-shared keys (version 1.3.1/2014), and that feature was never ported (as opposed to e.g. configurable proposals that were added to the KDE version a few months ago, after originally being added with 1.4.2/2017). I don't know whether that was an oversight or a conscious decision (PSKs are usually a bad choice for remote access scenarios, compared to e.g. EAP with a server certificate, and the GKT frontend actually enforces a minimum of 20 characters).

Comment: wow. just for curiosity: would it have been possible to find this out without your experience?